# How can I disable the the button? (GUI)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making simple calculator and I've implemented all the functions except one function.
As you know, dots must be used only once until the new number comes. So I want to make the (.) button disabled after used once and make it available again when I use symbol or C.
I was thinking about changing the button text by using configure method.

Here's my code:

```py
from tkinter import*
w1 = Tk()
w1.title("My Calculator") 
show = Entry(w1, width=33, bg="yellow") 
show.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)
btn_list = [ 
    '7','8','9','/','C',
    '4','5','6','*','',
    '1','2','3','-','',
    '0','.','=','+','']
index_row = 1 
index_col = 0 
def click(button): 
    if button == "=":  
        value = eval(show.get()) 
        s = str(value) 
        show.delete(0,"end") 
        show.insert(END,s) 
    elif button=="C": 
        show.delete(0,"end") 
    else: 
        show.insert(END,button) 
for btn_text in btn_list: 
    def go(k=btn_text): 
        click(k)
    Button(
        w1, text=btn_text, width=5, command=go
    ).grid(row=index_row, column=index_col) 
    index_col += 1 
    if index_col > 4: 
        index_row += 1  
        index_col = 0

w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: You will have to store your buttons in a list or dict, but you can disable any button by saying `btn["state"] = 'disabled'`, and setting it back to `'normal'` to turn it on.

Comment: Config is another. Like btn.config(state='disabled') and then 'normal'

Comment: Two ways, 1: Make a function and count the '.' and set btns state. 2: Validation on the entry.

Comment: I'm so glad that you helped me,
really helpful, but I cannot figure out of the name of buttons,,, there's name error,, Can you guys help me little more...? I'm so sorry xc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use a tkinter variable and `trace` it.

```
var = StringVar()
show = Entry(w1, width=33, bg="yellow", textvariable=var) 

def validate(*args):
    if var.get().count('.') > 1:
        var.set(var.get()[:-1])

var.trace('w',validate)
```

There are more than just one way to do this, starting with storing input in the list, or storing the specific button as a variable and so on. There are also different ways to loop through the texts easily.

Updated because your *professor* has not taught you the previous method(yet):

```
def click(button): 
    ..... # Same stuff

    if show.get().count('.') >= 1:
        dot_btn.config(state='disabled')
    else:
        dot_btn.config(state='normal')

for btn_text in btn_list: 
    def go(k=btn_text): 
        click(k)
    if btn_text == '.':
        dot_btn = Button(w1, text=btn_text, width=5, command=go)
        dot_btn.grid(row=index_row, column=index_col) 
    else:
        Button(
            w1, text=btn_text, width=5, command=go
        ).grid(row=index_row, column=index_col) 
    index_col += 1 
    if index_col > 4: 
        index_row += 1  
        index_col = 0
```

This looping method is really beating around the bush, directly you could just use nested loops and get your desired output, you would not even need to made `index_row` and `index_col`. Never limit your understanding to what your professor or mentor has taught you, be ready to explore and learn more(maybe you will end up teaching him :P).

---

Note that using `eval()` to do mathematical expressions alone is poor, it opens a whole new galaxy of security issues.

Comment: Really cool idea! but sadly,, I cannot use this because my professor hasn't given the lecture about that.. anyway Thank you!!

Comment: @daegalibboobboo22 I have updated the code and made it possible with really basic assignment and stuff.

Comment: @daegalibboobboo22 Also I hope you have been taught the bad effects of `eval()`, if not just run it past your mentor, its worth mentioning to not use it here(barefooted).

Comment: Thank you so much I'm so touched :c I wish you have a great day!